# Only mget new files with smbclient

Tags: smbclient

I'm using smbclient to access a shared Windows file system. I cannot mount it, because I don't have the permissions.

How do I mget only the files which are new or have been updated? (Likewise mput).

I don't think I can use rsync, because rsync only works if one mounts the Windows FS, which I can't do. I can only access it via smbclient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the archive bit (assuming no one else is fiddling with the archive bits on the files you're interested in).

Windows sets the bit whenever a file is created or modified.

```
smb: \> archive 2
```

Will tell SMB only to operate on files that have that bit set, and to reset it to zero when done.

So this will help with `mget`. For `mput` you want the opposite -- and the serverside archive bit won't help you see which of your own files has been modified, so this solution only works for `mget`.

This activity (getting only changed files and resetting their archive bits) is common enough to have its own command line option as well. See the `-T` or `--tar` option with the `c` (create) and `g` (incremental) flags.